# Jquery code for deleting a selected file, same like we do in gmail for attachment

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have written a code in jquery to upload a document, where we can select n number of file and then click on submit to upload it on server. How to delete a selected file ?
I have selected a file to upload but now I want it to delete, same like we do in gmail for attachments (we select an attachment and if we want to delete it we can delete and upload another one).
So how to delete a selected file using jquery ?

Following is my upload code which helps me to select required file to uplaod :

```
$('#add_more1').click(function(){
        var current_count= $('input[type="file"]').length ;
        var next_count = current_count + 1;
        $('#file_upload1').prepend('<p><input style="margin-left:10px" type="file" name="file_' + next_count + '"/></p>');
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `span` tag (use delete icon class from any suitable css library and give id to this `span`) with your `input` each time.

```
$('#id').click(function(){
 $('input[name="file_' + next_count + '"]').remove();
}
```